# Gerund and infinitive

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

We know some verbs followed by gerunds.   When these verbs  used with noun like in my example , should we always use them with infinitives  ?

"Shop doesn't allow smoking." (Without noun )

"I allow you to smoke in my car."  (With noun)

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter for each particular verb what kinds of objects it can take: sometimes verbs with the same meaning take different kinds of objects.

In the case of *allow*, it can take a gerund ("allow smoking") or an infinitive clause *with explicit subject* ("allow you to smoke"). But it does not take a bare infinitive ("*allow smoke") or a bare infinitive with *to*: ("*allow to smoke").